# Transferring info from one DataGridView to another

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview

For class I have to make an application that can create members that can create products and a sale form to create a bill. I am having problems removing a product from a DataGridView and adding it to the carts DataGridView. I am having problems with binding data. Here is what I have:

```
DataTabe t = ProductDB.getProducts()
products_dgv.DataSource = t;

DataTable d = new DataTable();
d.Columns.Add("Name");
d.Columns.Add("Price");
d.Columns.Add("ProductId");
d.Columns.Add("MemberId");
cart_dgv.DataSource = d;

private void addToCart_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string tempName = products_dgv.Rows[products_dgv.CurrentRow.Index].Cells["Name"].Value.ToString);
    string tempPrice = products_dgv.Rows[products_dgv.CurrentRow.Index].Cells["Price"].Value.ToString);
    //...
    String[] rowArray = new string[] {tempName, tempPrice, tempId, tempCond, tempMemberId, tempDesc};
    d.Rows.Add(rowArray[0]);
    products_dgv.Rows.RemoveAt(products_dgv.SelectedRows[0].Index);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem is the following line:

```
products_dgv.Rows.RemoveAt(products_dgv.SelectedRows[0].Index);
```

Earlier in the code, you access the row using:

```
products_dgv.Rows[products_dgv.CurrentRow.Index]
```

Based on this, and assuming the earlier code works correct, the remove line should be:

```
products_dgv.Rows.RemoveAt(products_dgv.CurrentRow.Index);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have not been able to make it to that line of code yet. I am still having problems transferring the info, but that will be of help in the near future hopefully :D

Comment: @user1084448: Where exactly are you having problems?